# LuaBind and package.loadlib

Tags: lua, luabind

I'm trying to go through the tutorial with luabind here, http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind/docs.html, however i'm having trouble loading the library. I'm currently using version 5.1 of lua, so I believe I would use package.loadlib instead of loadlib. I made a simple dll which is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <luabind\luabind.hpp>

void greet()
{
std::cout << "Hello world!\n";
}

extern "C" int init(lua_State* L)
{
luabind::open(L);

luabind::module(L)
    [
        luabind::def("greet", &greet)
    ];


return 0;
}
```

This builds just fine. However I get an error in lua when I try to run this code:

```
package.loadlib("LuaTestLib.dll", "init")
greet()
```

It states that greet is nil. How do I load the functions from the dll properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the first two sentences of [`package.loadlib`'s documentation](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-package.loadlib):

> Dynamically links the host program with the C library `libname`. Inside this library, looks for a function `funcname` and **returns this function as a C function**.

(emphasis added)

This doesn't *execute* `funcname`. It simply returns it as a function for you to call. You still have to call it:

```
package.loadlib("LuaTestLib.dll", "init")()
```

Comment: Be aware that the name might be `_init` or some other variation.