# Can't load shared library (compiled with C++ and Luabind) package into Lua

Tags: c++, lua, luabind

I have compiled the shared library for the ["basic usage" example](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind/docs.html#basic-usage) from the Luabind docs. However, I can't get it to call from Lua.

*lbtest.cpp*

```
extern "C"
{
    #include "lua.h"
}
#include <iostream>
#include <luabind/luabind.hpp>

void greet()
{
    std::cout << "hello world!\n";
}

extern "C" int init(lua_State* L)
{
    using namespace luabind;

    open(L);

    module(L)
    [
        def("greet", &greet)
    ];

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles to liblbtest.so. However, when I run the commands (as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561159/luabind-and-package-loadlib))

```
> lua
> package.loadlib('liblbtest.so', 'init')()
> greet()
```

I get this error:

> stdin:1: attempt to call global 'greet' (a nil value) stack traceback:
>   stdin:1: in main chunk   [C]: ?

I have tried a few tests:

```
> fn, err = package.loadlib('liblbtest.so', 'init')
> print(fn)
nil

> fn, err = package.loadlib('liblbtest.so', 'init')()
stdin:1: attempt to call a nil value
stack traceback:
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: ?

> fn, err = package.loadlib('liblbtest.so', '_init')()
> print(fn)
nil

> fn, err = package.loadlib('liblbtest.so', '_init')
> print(fn)
function 0x1332e90
```

All of those `loadlib` calls led to the same error in calling `greet()` (the nil value as laid out earlier). It is interesting that the last one at least seems to return a function.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 with Lua 5.1.5.

How do I get this to work?

---

**UPDATE**

I did manage to get a different error when I dropped the '.so' suffix and began using the `require` syntax (as per [this Lua mailing list conversation](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2006-05/msg00146.html))

```
> require('liblbtest')
error loading module 'liblbtest' from file './liblbtest.so':
    ./liblbtest.so: undefined symbol: luaopen_liblbtest
stack traceback:
    [C]: at 0x0047aff0
    [C]: in function 'require'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x00406670
```

However, using the `nm -gC liblbtest.so` command I don't see that symbol exported. How do I make that happen?

Comment: Using `ldd -r <yourobject>` and (perhaps)  `ldd -d <yourobject>` are you seeing everything being exported as expected?

Comment: @M4rc: I am. Or at least I believe so. The dependencies all appear to point to the right directories. I am leaning towards the idea that it has less to do with my shared object and more to do with how I load it into the Lua script. But I am open to being incorrect

Comment: If you run `readelf -Ws` are you seeing your `init` function and `greet` function in there? AFAIK `_init()` might be reserved for C++'s entrypoint.

Comment: @M4rc I do see greet as `_ZL5greetv` . I think I see init as `_ZStL8__ioint`

Comment: I can't entirely disconcern what it is -- you can run `c++filt _ZStL8__ioint` to demangle it on your platform. I believe it's the entry point for stl initialization, which would probably be `cout` in your case.

Comment: @M4rc: You're right. However, the greet function is what I thought it was. I don't see init explicitly anywhere

Comment: just as a matter of curiosity -- as I don't know LUA all that well, can you declare the `init` intialization function anything. For grins, `foo` and try using `package.loadlib('liblbtest.so', 'foo')()`. Just to see if that gets us what we're looking for.

Comment: If this is still relevant, can you show how you compile your module?

Answer (score 1):

Your C DLL does not follow format of lua C api DLL. Please try:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int luaopen_liblbtest(lua_State* L)
{
    lua_register(L, "init", init);
    return 1;
}
```